# How do I update first row of a particular column of Pyspark dataframe with a constant?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I write equivalent of

`df['col4'].iloc=0`

in Pyspark?

I know that this operation is not idle in a big data environment & spark dataframe is immutable. But how do I do it if its really required in Pyspark?

Thanks

Comment: Pyspark dataframes aren't mutable. Unlike the Pandas ones.

Comment: I understand that. But how do I work around that if its absolutely necessary.

Comment: what is your definition of `first row` for a distributed dataset?

Comment: Assuming data is loaded from a csv to spark. The 1st row in the csv is what I am referring to.

Comment: Or what about spark_df.head(1) ?

Comment: You have to set an order. Spark doesn't preserve order

Comment: I would suggest having an identifier for this row in terms of a key. Then create a new column based on an if-else statement in a udf. Use the new column for your operations